# Nginx reverse proxy setting

Tags: nginx, proxy, server, reverse, setting

I am totally new to Nginx and need your help.
Basically I have a single server with single IP address, but I want to host two different web application within the server with different domain name. So, basically, for each domain name, I want it to redirect to different port number. I tried below and got an error

```
[root@mysvr nginx]# nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:41
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Following is the Nginx setting. Line 41 is where the proxy_pass is.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name server1.com www.server1.com;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1003;
}

server {  
  listen 80;
  server_name server2.com www.server2.com;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1:1004;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you check the docs for [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass), `proxy_pass` needs to be in a `location`, `if in location` or `limit_except` block. You have it in a `server` block.

Try replacing your usage of `proxy_pass` with

```
location / {
    proxy_pass ...
}
```